# Dataset for distribution of different systems for 'yes' and 'no' cross-linguistically?

Tags: syntax, reference-request, words, datasets

The [Wikipedia article for 'Yes and no'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#Related_words_in_other_languages_and_translation_problems) lists various distinct, common, systems for expressing the affirmative and the negative, ranging from no explicit terms (instead relying on echo responses) to four-form systems, e.g. in Middle English.

However, I could not find any large-scale database cataloguing the distribution of each of these systems cross-linguistically. I have tried looking on WALS, but the closest entries I could find were either on the yes-or-no questions themselves ([#116A](https://wals.info/feature/116A#2/22.6/153.1)), or on only negative particles ([#112A](https://wals.info/feature/112A#2/19.3/152.8) - but little/no reference to how these words fit into a larger system of negation). Furthermore, the aforementioned Wikipedia article doesn't list any such large-scale references in its sources, instead just providing evidence for the systems in each of the individual languages mentioned.

Is there any available research documenting the presence/distribution of these systems cross-linguistically? At a high level, I'd just like to get an idea for what percentage of languages employs each of these systems, but seeing this broken down by family/on a WALS-style map would be great.